# iOS build settings Property List Output Encoding

Tags: ios

What's Property List Output Encoding for? If it is set to binary, does it actually compress the plist files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If set to `binary`, Xcode appears to take in any XML property lists and to save them into the application bundle as binary property lists.  A binary property list has a more compact file format than an XML property list, but I don't know if you'd call it compressed.

From the [Property List Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-SW2):

> XML property lists are more portable
>   than the binary alternative and can be
>   manually edited, but binary property
>   lists are much more compact; as a
>   result, they require less memory and
>   can be read and written much faster
>   than XML property lists. In general,
>   if your property list is relatively
>   small, the benefits of XML property
>   lists outweigh the I/O speed and
>   compactness that comes with binary
>   property lists.

Comment: It also appears that Xcode only exports files at the app bundle level and doesn't export any files in folder references to binary format.